# How can I limit the max number of Kubernetes pods to a specific number

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, cicd

## Problem

I've got a Kubernetes deployment of 20 replicas that needs runs long celery tasks. We deploy frequently to our cluster (at most ~every 10 mins). I set a long termination period of 3 hours for my pods so the tasks don't get interrupted. The problem is, on every deploy Kubernetes tries to create an additional 20 pods. How do I keep Kubernetes from scheduling additional pods before the existing ones are terminated?

## Release

My release is a GitHub action that does a helm upgrade and swaps in the new image tag that was just built.

```
helm upgrade --kube-context SK2 --install 
-f ./kube/helm/p1/values_SK2.yaml 
-n $REPOSITORY_NAME 
--set image.tag=$GIT_COMMIT 
$REPOSITORY_NAME 
./kube/helm/p1 
--atomic --debug --history-max=100 --timeout 6m
```

## Attempt 1

I tried to set a RollingUpdate strategy with the maxUnavilable to 20 and the max surge to 1 so that it would only ever create 1 additional pod on the deployments, but not schedule new pods until all the old pods are terminated.

```
strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 20
      maxSurge: 1
```

## Attempt 2

I've also tried pinning the image to latest instead of updating the image on deploy then changing the deployment's image tag after the helm install.

```
kubectl --context SK2 -n p1 set image deployment/celery-io-long celery-io-long=stringking/p1:$GIT_COMMIT
```

Both of these techniques have the end result of creating a new batch of 20 pods on deployment before the old ones are terminated. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

setting the maxUnavailable value to 20, means that 20 will be unavailable simultaneously during the rolling update and will spin up new pods with the new deployment.

You should set its value to:

```
maxUnavailable: 1 
maxSurge: 1
```

This ensures that only 1 out of the 20 existing pods will be terminated once the rolling update has started and doesn't schedule additional pods until the existing ones are terminated.

Comment: I actually don't care if all 20 are unavailable.  These are just pods running celery jobs, the next pod will pick up the jobs. The issue is that k8 is creating 20 new pods in each rollout. Since I need to have a long kill time b/c they are long running jobs, the pods keep stacking up on each deploy.